# vb.net Add different types and size of fonts to one button

Tags: vb.net

I am making one project where i want to use two differnt fonts types and size in one button. For example like in Windows Defender where you have information about what does button do and under this you have security message in different size and type of font in one button.

For this button i have no line with code, but is here anyone who did this kind of stuff?

Comment: A Button provided by what UI Platform? (WPF, WinForms, UWP, Xamarin, other)

Comment: Just so I'm clear, you want something like 2 lines of text on your button, one line with for example 12pt font, the other line with 8pt font?

Comment: Assuming WinForms, it's not possible by simply setting properties. You would need to handle the `Paint` event and make multiple calls to `e.Graphics.DrawString`, each with different fonts.

Comment: @Jimi I am using WinForms

Comment: @Hursey Yes, so i want to do it

Comment: @jmcilhinney does that mean that when I move the cursor trough the button, text will show up or the text still shows?

Comment: Are you asking whether the text on the `Button` will be drawn over the top of the cursor? If so, why can't you take the two minutes to test for yourself? Add a control, handle an event, write a line of code, run the project, move the mouse. Now you have the answer to your question.